# SFSafariViewController: how to provide custom activities?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

The WWDC session of Safari View Controller mentioned that apps could provide custom activities through the method `func safariViewController(controller: SFSafariViewController, activityItemsForURL URL: NSURL, title: String?) -> [UIActivity]` of the delegate `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`. I have tried to implement this method, but it is *not called* after I present the `SFSafariViewCntroller`. I also implemented another optional method of that delegate, `func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_: SFSafariViewController)`, which does get called. I tried to add the "@objc" keyword to my method (required by some other protocols), but it seems not to change anything.

I am wondering what could go wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example code for your reference. In your main view:

```
func safariViewController(controler: SFSafariViewController, activityItemsForURL: NSURL, title: String?) -> [UIActivity] {
    //global variable for the url to be shared
    webPageUrl = activityItemsForURL.absoluteString
    //global variable for the title to be shared
    webPageTitle = title!
    let wcActivity = WeChatActivity()
    let wcMoment = WeChatMoment()
    return [wcActivity, wcMoment]
}
```

Custom activities 1

```
import UIKit

class WeChatActivity : UIActivity{

    override init() {
        self.text = ""

    }

    var text:String?

    override func activityType()-> String {
        return "WeChat"
    }

    override func activityImage()-> UIImage?
    {
        return UIImage(named: "WeChat")!
    }

    override func activityTitle() -> String
    {
        return "微信好友"
    }


    override class func activityCategory() -> UIActivityCategory{
        return UIActivityCategory.Action
        //you can change to .Share and it'll appear in the share line
    }

    func getURLFromMessage(message:String)-> NSURL
    {
        var url = "whatsapp://"

        if (message != "")
        {
            url = "\(url)send?text=\(message)"
        }

        return NSURL(string: url)!
    }


    override func canPerformWithActivityItems(activityItems: [AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return true;
    }

    override func performActivity() {
        shareToWeChat("ftcweixin://?url=\(webPageUrl)&title=\(webPageTitle)&description=\(webPageDescription)&img=\(webPageImageIcon)&to=chat")
    }

}
```

Custom Activity 2:

```
import UIKit

class WeChatMoment : UIActivity{

    override init() {
        self.text = ""
    }

    var text:String?


    override func activityType()-> String {
        return "WeChatMoment"
    }

    override func activityImage()-> UIImage?
    {
        return UIImage(named: "Moment")!
    }

    override func activityTitle() -> String
    {
        return "微信朋友圈"
    }


    override class func activityCategory() -> UIActivityCategory{
        return UIActivityCategory.Action
    }

    func getURLFromMessage(message:String)-> NSURL
    {
        var url = "whatsapp://"

        if (message != "")
        {
            url = "\(url)send?text=\(message)"
        }

        return NSURL(string: url)!
    }


    override func canPerformWithActivityItems(activityItems: [AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return true;
    }

    override func performActivity() {
        shareToWeChat("ftcweixin://?url=\(webPageUrl)&title=\(webPageTitle)&description=\(webPageDescription)&img=\(webPageImageIcon)&to=moment")
    }
}
```

You'll be able to see the two new icons in the action line of the action sheet. You can also change it to appear in the share line, as explained in the code.

One final note, there are pitfalls for WeChat sharing on Safari View, as WeChat doesn't conform to Safari's sharing standard. You can click the WeChat Share icon and WeChat will be able to share. But you can only get the page title and url in Safari View's page, unlike with WKWebView where you can get everything using evaluateJavaScript. So you'll need to get the share image and description (for sharing to friends) from other places.

Comment: before I try, just one little question…how did you know that I want to add WeChat sharing support (well otherwise built-in sharing extensions would be sufficient)

Comment: Almost all major social networks makes developers life easier by following open standards and being accepted as build-ins. WeChat is the only exception that I can think of. But they are freakishly popular. So if a developer is going through so much trouble to  customize the action sheet, it's very likely to be WeChat share. By the way, if you need the full project, I can send you the link on GitHub.